# Personalised batch email with Mailgun in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun, bulk-email

I'm looking to send *personalised* batch e-mails to a large number of users. By this I mean that I would like to set up a template e-mail and inject each user's information into it before sending it.

Of course, this can easily be achieved with Laravel by looping through user data and using the Mailer (Or `Mail` facade) methods (Such as `send`, `raw`, `queue` etc.):

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $data = ['user' => $user];
    $this->mailer->queue($views, $data, function($message) use($user) {
        $message->to($user->email, $user->name);
    });
}
```

However, considering the volume of e-mails I would like to send, this would be far too slow for my needs. After some research I have discovered that Mailgun supports sending personalised batch e-mails using their API. From their website:

> Batch sending
>
> With a single API call, you can send up to 1000 fully personalized emails.
>
> Mailgun will properly assemble the MIME message and send the email to each of your users individually. That makes sending large volumes of email a lot faster and a lot less resource intensive.

- I was wondering if Laravel supports personalised batch e-mail sending in this way? I haven't managed to find anything in the documentation or the code to support this.
- Are there any existing packages available for Laravel to support this?

Of course, I could happily implement this using Mailgun's API directly or using any available SDKs, but just wanted to check to see if it is supported by Laravel first.

Comment: I was looking for this same thing a few months back and couldn't find any ready made solution, so I ended up writing the function myself. It's really simple though using the Mailgun batches.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's a shame. Would you mind posting an answer and potentially include how you achieved it? I can accept if I don't get any more responses.

Comment: I'm using [Swiftmailer Mailgun bundle](https://github.com/tehplague/swiftmailer-mailgun-bundle) with [Sending Emails in Batch with swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#sending-emails-in-batch) for such thing in my Symfony apps. If you can use this bundle in your Laravel app, you shouldn't look any further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I solved an identical situation since I couldn't find any ready made solution.

```
        $subscribers = Subscriber::active()->get();
        $batch = 0;
        $batch_subscribers = array();
        $batch_subscribers_data = array();
        foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber)
        {
            $batch_subscribers[] = $subscriber->mail;
            $batch_subscribers_data[$subscriber->mail] = array(
                "id" => $subscriber->id,
                "mail" => $subscriber->mail,
                "name" => $subscriber->name
            );
            $batch++;
            if($batch < 999){
                continue;
            }
            $input['to'] = $batch_subscribers;
            $input['vars'] = $batch_subscribers_data;
            Mailgun::send('email/email-base', ['input' => $input],
                function ($message) use ($input) 
                {
                    $message->subject($input['asunto']);
                    $message->to($input['to']);
                    $message->replyTo("reply@address.com");
                    $message->recipientVariables($input['vars']);
                });
            $batch_subscribers = array();
            $batch_subscribers_data = array();
            $batch = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To anybody who still wants to use Laravel Mailable,

you can override the Mailgun transport class to tweak the payload:

```
  /**
   * Get the HTTP payload for sending the Mailgun message.
   *
   * @param  \Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage  $message
   * @param  string  $to
   * @return array
   */
  protected function payload(Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage $message, $to)
  {
    // use laravel official mailgun transport when
    // batch_sending in config not set, or
    // only 1 recipient
    if (! $this->batchSending || count($message->getTo()) === 1) {
      return parent::payload($message, $to);
    }

    // batch sending
    $ret = [
      'auth' => [
        'api',
        $this->key,
      ],
      'multipart' => [
        [
          'name' => 'message',
          'contents' => str_replace(
            $message->getHeaders()->get('to')->toString(),
            'To: %recipient%'.PHP_EOL,
            $message->toString()
          ),
          'filename' => 'message.mime',
        ],
      ],
    ];

    $recipients = [];
    foreach ($message->getTo() as $address => $name) {
      $ret['multipart'][] = [
        'name' => 'to',
        'contents' => "$name <$address>",
      ];

      $recipients[$address] = [
        'name' => $name,
      ];
    }

    $ret['multipart'][] = [
      'name' => 'recipient-variables',
      'contents' => json_encode($recipients),
    ];

    return $ret;
  }
```

I just created a package https://github.com/leondeng/laravel-batch-mailgun for this, please have a try and feedback me if any issue, thanks!